# Notes tied to rests?

Tags: guitar, notation

This is the end of Leo Brouwer's study 4 from the "Estudios Sencillos":

[image: score]

Some notes here are tied to rests, or so it seems. What did Brouwer want the performer to do?

Comment: A related scenario is discussed in [Understanding the ending of Debussy's La fille aux cheveux de lin](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/58698/70803).

Comment: These notes aren't tied to rests, they're tied to nothing. You can just as well employ a "laissez vibrer" at the end of a piece, with *nothing* following. In all cases the meaning is "let strings ring as long as they will, regardless of tempo".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means to let the chords ring, rather than cutting them off at the moment of the rest. Brouwer doesn't want the chords cut off; rather he wants them to fade naturally. This is a fairly common way to notate that. Sometimes such "ties to rests" will be accompanied by "l.v." or "Laissez Vibrer" ("let vibrate").

Here is an example from Debussy's Prelude for Piano (Preludes, Book 2, Number 1), the final two measures. The half-note chords are allowed to ring, via the damper pedal, and decay naturally (i.e., with the dampers lifted), while the two final chords are played.

[image: Debussy "(...Brouillards)"]

Comment: Unless one actually knows the meaning, tying to rests isn't intuitive. L.v is.

Comment: @Tim Not sure about that. How is two letters intuitive if you have no idea what they stand for (and even in which language the phrase might be)? I'd say both notations are something you either know or don't know, not something you can easily guess. "Laissez vibrer" can be comprehensible if you know just a little French, but "L. v." is opaque.

Comment: @Tim  With all due respect please don't state personal preference as an absolute.   The meaning of  a tie to a rest is obvious to a number of musicians I know.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - hadn't realised I did state anything as a personal preference. Sorry.

Comment: @Tim: An L.V. notation might for some instruments be preferred if no notes should be damped, but using ties would allow for the possibility that some notes should be damped while others are allowed to ring.  The difference in notation might also be relevant if a piece might be performed by different kinds of instruments.  It may be that if one is playing a piece on an instrument where notes would naturally decay over a period of four bars, letting the notes ring for that whole time may be preferable to damping them sooner, but if one is playing on a sustaining instrument, ...

Comment: ...having the note stop after one bar would be preferable to having it stop at some other time or having it sustain for the whole four bars.

Comment: @supercat - in a lot of cases, the notes would (should) have been written out with whatever duration the composer wanted. The main case I find for l.v., which more often than not, isn't even notated, is with classical guitar pieces, where cutting notes off as writ. makes it all sound wrong. I inherited a student from a teacher who had taught just that, and the (exam) pieces sounded just awful, and I'm certain would have got him a fail.

Comment: @Tim: In many cases, the "best" duration for a note will depend upon the combination of instruments used to perform a piece and, in some cases, the acoustics of the space in which it is being performed.  Depending upon the nature of the piece, I'd interpret ties connected to rests as an invitation for a performer to exercise judgment as to what duration would be most appropriate given the instruments and venue.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me as a piano player so I'm trying to understand. Usually, the damper stops the sound from the piano as soon as I lift my finger from the key. If I want the let the note ring, I press the sustain pedal to keep the damper off the string as long as I hold the pedal (though this does all the dampers at once). There's no way I know of to just "let a chord ring out naturally" on the piano. The only thing that comes to mind that **might** do this is the [Sostenudo Pedal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_pedals#Sostenuto_pedal). Is that perhaps what this is for?

Comment: @Chipster That's a good point. The Debussy (and the general case) employ the sustain pedal. What I meant by "decay" naturally, is that the strings are allowed to vibrate, damperless, until the sound fades out, rather than cutting off the sound (by releasing the pedal) at a specific time. I'll clarify the post to make that explicit.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense to me now. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Depending upon the style of music, I would be inclined to interpret notes tied to rest as an invitation to hold notes beyond the indicated duration if, *in a performer's judgment*, such treatment would make the piece sound better *on the particular instruments being used, and in the particular venue where the piece is being performed*, than playing them precisely as marked.

In many cases, it may be desirable to have a slight "echo" of notes that are played in one measure persist into the next measure, but for the sound of such notes to be much quieter than the sound of notes played in the later measure.  If a piece is being performed in a very resonant space, or on a piano whose dampers quench string vibrations relatively slowly, this may naturally happen even if notes are cut off precisely at the end of a measure.  If the piece is played on a piano with very fast-acting dampers in an acoustically dry space, however, the start of the next measure may sound very "empty" if notes were cut off as written.  Unless a piece is written for a very specific purpose, there's no way a compiler will be able to anticipate the acoustics of the places it will be performed, or the characteristics of the instruments of the instruments that will be used, but a performer who is using the actual instruments in the space would be far better able (perhaps in conjunction with other people sitting in the audience area) to judge such things.